# when i use textview.getid(),why the result comes out is not the the one i defined for textview in the xml

Tags: android

Assuming i got 3 data:i=01,j=02,k=03 and i want to set these 3 data indiviually into 3 textViews that defined with ids:@+id/tv01,@+id/tv02,@+id/tv03. The following is what i have tried:

```
if (textview.getid().contain(i))
    textView.settext(i)
```

But when i use textview.getid(), why the result comes out is not the the one i defined for textview in the xml? Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do it same way you are doing.
You can manually set the ids of TextView by using setId().

For eg.

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv01);
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv02);
tv1.setId(1); 
tv2.setId(2);
```

and for getting use getId() you will get what you have set.

Answer (score 4):

When you use textview.getId(), you get the id of the textview as generated in R.java file,and not what you have defined in "@+id/xxx"

---

So if you want to play around with ids, you should do something like :

```
    if(textview.getid() == R.id.textview) { 
       // do awesome stuff
    }
```